# Android 11 Preview not working in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-11

When i configure a new Android Emulator in Android Studio with **Android R (API 30)** the emulator still shows up as **Android Q (API 29)**

When i check the settings for an update it shows that the system is up to date and Android version 10 is running even when i configured the emulator to run Android 11.

Even the **Device File Explorer in Android Studio** says it's running 10.

Android SDK Build-Tools 30-rc4 are also installed, so i'm not sure why it's not working.

[image]

**Emulator Config**

[image]

Comment: Have you checked on the file system that you haven't accidentally already made an older API 29 emulator with the exact same name? Have you created the emulator form scratch (with a new name)?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the one you are configuring may not even be working. First, check if the **Tools > SDK Manager** has that Android version and that it is **checked** - not blank; it should auto-install if it wasn't already. Then come back to your **AVD Manager** (also in Tools) to setup up your new device. This should work. Or, check if any Edit was done on it (possibly from cloning). If so, re-edit them back to your desired API Level.